# Reading Principles of Mathematical Logic by Hilbert

Tags: logic, reference-request, formal-systems

I want to read *Principles of Mathematical Logic* by Hilbert and Ackermann. However, I don't know if this is an introductory level text. So I was wondering, is there some background one should have before reading this book?

Comment: It is a textbook, and this it is self-contained: it is quite an old one, and thus there are many more recent ones.